# Forcing request timeout on nginx?

Tags: nginx

Is there a way to tell nginx to timeout a request after a certain length of time, regardless of whether data continues to flow through or not?

I know send_timeout will kill it if no data is picked up by the client after so long, but if the client is, for instance, using "curl --limit-rate 1" or something, is there a setting that says "no matter what else is going on, timeout a request after (x) seconds."?